# React Native | TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

I came across a project in React native. My problem is that when I click on it, it focuses on TextInput and opens and closes the keyboard immediately. This happens again when I move to a new page. It happens only at the first click. It returns to normal in the following ones. Has anyone encountered this situation before?

Edit: Only happening on android no problem in iOS.

Code:

```
<TextInput styles.textınput 
style = {} onChangeText = {(text) =>
thisSetState ((text)} 
this.state.text value = {} TextAlign = { "center"} />
```

Comment: I remember I encounter this before,but really cannot recall how I fix it.Something to do with 'Keyboard.dismiss()' and Keyboard.dismiss() fires even when you click on a TextInput?

Comment: Can you share the code please

Comment: @Imjaad 
nothing in the code :D just <TextInput
styles.textınput style = {}
onChangeText = {(text) => thisSetState ((text)}
this.state.text value = {}
TextAlign = { "center"}
/> . Nothing else on the page is just one input.